# How to extend an NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, gparted

I have a Linux and a Windows partition and want to extend the windows one.

I already decreased the size of the linux partition via gparted, the problem is that the unused space is on the end of the disc, so I cannot add it to the windows partition which is before the Linux one.

Can anyone explain me how I can re-allocate the partitions, so that I can extend the NTFS one?

I couldn't find any way doing this, at least not in GParted.

Here is a screenshot explaining my problem:

[image]

```
/dev/sda2 is my windows partition, which I want to extend
/dev/sda3 is my linux partition, which I made smaller already.
```

Comment: you want to add 119 GB unallocated space to the /dev/sda2 partition.Am i correct?

Comment: You have to move all logical partitions right, then shrink extended partition so unallocated is outside the extended. Anther alternative is just to make it another NTFS partition and use it as a shared data partition for both Windows & Linux.

Answer (score 1):

#### To add 119 GB unallocated space to the /dev/sda2 partition:

- Right-click on the `dev/sda3` extended partition and then select the option *Resize/Move*.
- click and Move the dragger to the extreme right,so that the 119 GB unallocated space will come just above to the `/dev/sda3`.
- Now right-click on the `/dev/sda2` partition and then select the option *Resize/Move* to add the unallocated space.That's all.

**NOTE:** Run all the above steps in Gparted  running on a live disk.

Comment: This sadly doesnt work. For some reason the left dragger is fixed, I only am able to move the right one.

Comment: click on the dragger and move it to extreme right.If not works,then upload the screenshot.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/f1zW9V7.jpg Its german but as you can see I can`t change to value of the free space the partition, only the one after it.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions hope this helps you. I am in a similar situation

Comment: I think I had the same problem a long time ago. When I rember correctly it's not possible to just move the whole extended partition (/dev/sda3). You have to resize/extend the extended partition (/dev/sda3) first, then move the partitions inside to the end and afterwards you can shrink the extended partition, creating space in between /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3.

Answer (score 1):

You must move your partitions such that the free space is next to the partition you are trying to expand first.

In your case, I believe that means you should move sda3, sda5, sda6, and sda7 all the way to the right.

Please exercise caution when you try this / make a backup. I have no idea what I am doing. I am trying it now, and I might have just ruined my MBR. I'll reboot and let you know ;)